# Can't fix unwanted unicorn 302 Found back to root domain

Tags: unicorn, http-status-code-302

When I go to http://git.niklasrosenstein.com, I always get redirected to http://niklasrosenstein.com. It then actually serves the content as if the server block below was matched, but of course under the wrong domain! I'm trying to find the source of this issue since 2 hours but I am now where I was when I started.

This is the only active `server` block in the whole NGinx configuration.

```
## GitLab
##
## Lines starting with two hashes (##) are comments with information.
## Lines starting with one hash (#) are configuration parameters that can be uncommented.
##
##################################
##        CONTRIBUTING          ##
##################################
##
## If you change this file in a Merge Request, please also create
## a Merge Request on https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/merge_requests
##
###################################
##         configuration         ##
###################################
##
## See installation.md#using-https for additional HTTPS configuration details.

upstream gitlab-workhorse {
  server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab-workhorse.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

## Normal HTTP host
server {
  ## Either remove "default_server" from the listen line below,
  ## or delete the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file. This will cause gitlab
  ## to be served if you visit any address that your server responds to, eg.
  ## the ip address of the server (http://x.x.x.x/)n 0.0.0.0:80 default_server;
  listen 80;
  # listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
  server_name git.niklasrosenstein.com;
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice
  root /home/git/gitlab/public;

  ## See app/controllers/application_controller.rb for headers set

  ## Individual nginx logs for this GitLab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    client_max_body_size 0;
    gzip off;

    ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;
  }
}
```

Here's the request/response information from the Chrome developer console.

[image]

What is going on? I want NGinx to match the server block for `git.niklasrosenstein.com`!

*PS: While I'm not working on this problem, I have re-enabled the sub-domain https://blog.niklasrosenstein.com but the behaviour described above stays the same*

---

**Update 1** I have updated my `/etc/hosts` file to contain the real public IP of my VPS for `git.niklasrosenstein.com` instead of `127.0.0.1`. That fixed the problem temporarily, though as soon as I reactivated a block that does rediction, it's the same problem again.

```
server {
  # Permanent redirect from the old domain and the root domain name
  # to the blog domain.

  listen          80;
  server_name     niklasrosenstein.de
                  www.niklasrosenstein.de
                  niklasrosenstein.com
                  www.niklasrosenstein.com;
  access_log      /home/www-data/blog/access-redirect.log access_csv_format;
  return          301   $scheme://blog.niklasrosenstein.com$request_uri;
}
```

---

**Update 2** It seems to be a problem with Unicorn rather than NGinx. Issue on GitLab CE: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1063

Comment: The redirect is probably originating from upstream. So either fix the problem at the source or maybe `proxy_redirect` can help.

Comment: @RichardSmith You are right, it seems like NGinx is not the problem but Unicorn is doing the redirect. Thanks for that hint. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/1063